# Records aren't saved to downloaded CSV

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv, csvhelper

I am using (er, attempting to, anyway) CsvHelper to write records to a CSV file, then download the file. Right now, the file downloads, but it is only writing "CsvHelper.CsvWriter" to the first column, in the first row. That's it. What am I missing?

**The Button Handler that initiates the download:**

```
protected void DownloadChargeDataAsCSV(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<ChargeDetail> charges = ChargeDetail.GetDetailsForPatient(lblPatientNum.Text, lblPatientName.Text);

    string attachment = "attachment; filename=MyCsvLol.csv";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "public");

    using (var textWriter = File.CreateText("MyCsvLol.csv"))
    using (var writer = new CsvWriter(textWriter))
    {
        foreach (var charge in charges)
        {
            writer.WriteRecord(charge);
        }

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(writer);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
}
```

**The Charge Detail Class:**

```
public class ChargeDetail
{
    public string PatientNumber { get; set; }
    public string PateintName { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string ChargeCode { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Qty { get; set; }
    public string UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public string ExtAmt { get; set; }

    public static List<ChargeDetail> GetDetailsForPatient(string patientNumber, string patientName)
    {
        List<ChargeDetail> charges = new List<ChargeDetail>();
        DataTable thisDT = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection thisConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            string SprocName = "GetChargeDetails";
            SqlDataAdapter thisAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(SprocName, thisConnection);
            thisAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            thisAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PatientNumber", patientNumber);
            thisAdapter.Fill(thisDT);
        }

        foreach (DataRow row in thisDT.Rows)
        {
            charges.Add(new ChargeDetail(patientNumber, patientName, row));
        }

        return charges;
    }

    public ChargeDetail(string patientNumber, string patientName, DataRow row)
    {
        this.PatientNumber = patientNumber;
        this.PateintName = patientName;
        this.Date = row["SrvcDate"].ToString();
        this.ChargeCode = row["ChargeCode"].ToString();
        this.Description = row["ChargeDescription"].ToString();
        this.Qty = row["HHY_Qty"].ToString();
        this.UnitPrice = row["PatPrice"].ToString();
        this.ExtAmt = row["ExtAmt"].ToString();
    }

    public ChargeDetail()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you meant to be using `textWriter` instead of `writer` in the `HttpContext` response?

Answer (score 2):

I needed something similar. I used the code posted by anwyatt, but I would occasionally got an empty file or imcomplete file in the response unless I first flushed the Stream Writer. Sorry I'm not allowed to comment on his answer, but thought I'd post this in case someone else has a similar issue.

```
protected void DownloadChargeDataAsCSV(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<ChargeDetail> charges = ChargeDetail.GetDetailsForPatient(lblPatientNum.Text, lblPatientName.Text);

    string attachment = "attachment; filename=ChargeDetails.csv";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "public");
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(memoryStream))
    using (var writer = new CsvWriter(streamWriter))
    {
        writer.WriteRecords(charges);
        streamWriter.Flush();
        memoryStream.Position = 0;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
    }
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't read the "writer". After saving the file, then read it back to send back to the user.

```
using (var textWriter = File.CreateText("MyCsvLol.csv"))
    using (var writer = new CsvWriter(textWriter))
    {
        foreach (var charge in charges)
        {
            writer.WriteRecord(charge);
        }       
    }

 HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(File.ReadAllText("MyCsvLol.csv"));
 HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

Comment: Now the downloaded CSV contains "System.String[]" instead of "CsvHelper.CsvWriter"

Comment: Double check whats stored in MyCsvLol.csv file by opening it in notepad. Verify if it has csv text that you are trying to save.

Comment: It doesn't. It only contains "System.String[]"

Comment: That means your csvwriter code isn't writing properly. You will need to fix that. I am not familiar with csvwriter library; but I would suggest that you simply verify functionality by writing without csv writer; then work to fix csv writer.

Comment: It actually wasn't the CSV code. I just posted an answer that worked.

Answer (score 0):

This got it working.

```
protected void DownloadChargeDataAsCSV(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<ChargeDetail> charges = ChargeDetail.GetDetailsForPatient(lblPatientNum.Text, lblPatientName.Text);

    string attachment = "attachment; filename=ChargeDetails.csv";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "public");
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(memoryStream))
    using (var writer = new CsvWriter(streamWriter))
    {
        writer.WriteRecords(charges);
        memoryStream.Position = 0;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
    }
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}
```